# How can I paste images into my markdown files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to paste the screenshot from clipboard gracefully in VS Code, VS Code will copy this image when the current specified directory and rename it according to the time

The built-in markdown plugin has a `markdown.experimental.copyFiles.destination` setting, but there is no documentation explaining how to configure it, and using the'Paste Image 'plugin for example has no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Since VS Code 1.79, the setting is no longer experimental, and is called `markdown.copyFiles.destination` ([source](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_markdowncopyfilesdestination)).

First you need to enable `editor.experimental.pasteActions.enabled` ("*Enable/disable running edits from extensions on paste.*"). Then you can set `markdown.experimental.copyFiles.destination` configuration according to its documentation:

> Defines where files copied created by drop or paste should be created. This is a map from globs that match on the Markdown document to destinations.
>
> The destinations may use the following variables:
>
> - `${documentFileName}` — The full filename of the Markdown document, for example: readme.md.
> - `${documentBaseName}` — The basename of Markdown document, for example: readme.
> - `${documentExtName}` — The extension of the Markdown document, for example: md.
> - `${documentDirName}` — The name of the Markdown document's parent directory.
> - `${documentWorkspaceFolder}` — The workspace folder for the Markdown document, for example: /Users/me/myProject. This is the same as `${documentDirName}` if the file is not part of a workspace.
> - `${fileName}` — The file name of the dropped file, for example: image.png.

For example, to paste any pasted images in the same directory as the markdown file you are pasting into, use:

```json
"markdown.experimental.copyFiles.destination": {
    "**/*": "${documentDirName}/"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I still don't know how to configure to rename the image when pasting it or is this feature not supported for the time being?

Comment: I think I probably get it, thanks

Comment: Just the first setting was needed in my case (`editor.experimental.pasteActions.enabled`). The second setting would be nice, but unfortunately didn't seem to do anything for me on paste.

Answer (score 9):

This has changed substantially in vscode Stable v1.79. See [Release Notes: copy media files to markdown](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_copy-external-media-files-into-workspace-on-drop-or-paste-for-markdown).

> Want to add an image or video into a Markdown document? Instead of
> wasting time first manually copying the file into your workspace and
> then adding a link to it, now you can just drop or paste the file into
> your Markdown. If the file currently isn't part of the workspace, VS
> Code will automatically copy the file into your workspace and insert a
> link to it:
>
> This also works great for image data in the clipboard. For example, if
> you take a screenshot with the Snipping tool on Windows, you can press
> Paste in a Markdown file and VS Code will create a new image file from
> the clipboard data and insert a Markdown image link to the new file.
> This also works on macOS if you hold the Ctrl key while taking a
> screenshot to copy it to the clipboard.

To do this make sure the following setting is set to `mediaFiles`, which is the default.

```
Markdown > Editor > File Paste: Copy Into Workspace  // default is mediaFiles, or never
Controls if files outside of the workspace that are pasted into a Markdown editor should be copied into the workspace. Use 'Markdown > Copy Files: Destination' to configure where copied files should be created.
```

Also these two settings must be enabled:

```
Markdown > Editor > File Paste: Enabled   // default is Enabled
Editor > Paste As: Enabled                // default is Enabled
```

Then when you copy an image for example to the clipboard and **PASTE** it into a markdown file, a link that looks like this

```
![Alt text](image.png)   // note that gif files are pasted as a simple png
```

is created in the markdown file and a file is created in the workspace called `image.png`.  Subsequent pastes will be named `image-1.png`, etc.

The above was for a **paste**, a **drag and drop** of an image file will have its original filename in the link and in the newly created file in the workspace.

The exact location of that file is determined by this setting:

[image: setting for destination of an image pasted into a markdown file]

See [Release Notes: copied file destination](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_markdowncopyfilesdestination).

> For example, if we want every Markdown file under `/docs` in our
> workspace to put new media files into an images directory specific to
> the current file, we can write:

```json
"markdown.copyFiles.destination": {   
  "/docs/**/*": "images/${documentBaseName}/"
}
```

> Now when a new file is pasted in `/docs/api/readme.md`, the image file
> is created at `/docs/api/images/readme/image.png`.
>
> You can even use simple regular expressions to transform variables in
> a similar way to snippets. For example, this transform uses only the
> first letter of the document file name when creating the media file

```json
"markdown.copyFiles.destination": {   
  "/docs/**/*": "images/${documentBaseName/(.).*/$1/}/" 
}
```

> When a new file is pasted into `/docs/api/readme.md`, the image will
> now be created under `/docs/api/images/r/image.png`.

Unfortunately, there is no variable for a timestamp as you requested.

There is more on controlling this behaviour at the links above, such as using these settings:

```
"markdown.copyFiles.overwriteBehavior"
"markdown.editor.drop.copyIntoWorkspace": "never"
"markdown.editor.filePaste.copyIntoWorkspace": "never"
```

Comment: Great answer. Their explanation,  " This is a map from globs that match **on the Markdown document** to destinations," is very ambiguous, which this helped me with. I thought that the glob should match the pasted object, so was futzing around with `Item=*.png` with no success

Answer (score 5):

Took me a bit of trial and error to figure out how this works. Setting `Item="**/*"` and `Value="images/"` will copy a file I paste into a Markdown file into the `images/` directory

[image]

Comment: Note: this experimental feature works when copying local images, or when screen snipping (Windows), but doesn’t activate when copying images from the browser.